# Getting file size with lseek command in c

Tags: c, operating-system

I was asked to find the size of the file usjng lseek command (without using stat) and i wrote the following code

```
int main()
{
    char buf[100], fn[10];
    int fd, i;
    printf("Enter file name\n");
        scanf("%s", fn);
    fd = open(fn, O_RDONLY);
    int size = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    printf("Size is %d", size);
    close(fd);
}
```

But i am getting -1 as file size, where am i going wrong

Comment: What does the manual say that lseek returns?

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure the filename you're entering is in the right directory?

Comment: lseek() repositions the file offset of the open file description
       associated with the file descriptor fd to the argument offset
       according to the directive whence

Comment: you didn't check if the open call worked

Comment: Is the file needed to be in same directory as the programm?

Comment: The filename specified must be an absolute path or a path relative to the current directory. It doesn't have to be in the same directory as the program.

Comment: Its working fine for me in my system ubuntu 16.04 , 64 bit , gcc compiler , can you please post the output window you are getting while running .  Are you sure that you have that file in current directory where you are executing binary when you entering the file_name only not with path.

Comment: Since you didn't check that the `open()` succeeded, the most likely problem is that you didn't open the file successfully, and therefore the `lseek()` fails and reports `-1`.  You've only allowed for a 9-character file name (plus terminal null byte); that isn't very long!  If you checked `errno` (from `<errno.h>`) after the `lseek()`, you'd probably find it contains `EBADF` (ditto after the `close()`).  Check that the `scanf()` works and that the `open()` works.

Comment: `lseek()` returns `off_t`, not `int`.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", fn);`  1)  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]'  always include a MAX_CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input field, to avoid buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior, as those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.   I.E.  `if( scanf("%9s", fn) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for file name failed\n" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve], which includes the statements for the needed header files

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use" `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu17` )  note: different compilers require different options to accomplish the same thing

Answer (score 1):

From `lseek` documentation available [online](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html):

> RETURN VALUE        
>          Upon successful completion, lseek() returns the resulting offset
>          location as measured in bytes from the beginning of the file.  **On
>          error, the value (off_t) -1 is returned and errno is set to indicate
>          the error.**

So you have to check the `errno` (print it if `lseek` returns `-1`):

The list of possible errors from the same [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html):

> ERRORS
>
> ```
>    EBADF  fd is not an open file descriptor.  
>    EINVAL whence is not valid.  Or: the resulting file offset would be
>           negative, or beyond the end of a seekable device.  
>    ENXIO  whence is SEEK_DATA or SEEK_HOLE, and the file offset is
>           beyond the end of the file.  
>    EOVERFLOW  The resulting file offset cannot be represented in an off_t.  
>    ESPIPE fd is associated with a pipe, socket, or FIFO.
> ```

In your case, it is most likely EBADF.

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. properly checks for errors
3. performs the desired functionality
4. uses proper variable typing

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main( void )
{
    char fn[10];
    int fd;
    printf("Enter file name\n");
    if( scanf("%9s", fn) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for file name failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if( (fd = open(fn, O_RDONLY) ) < 0 )
    {
        perror( "open failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    off_t  size = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    printf("Size is %ld", size);
    close(fd);
}
```